# Chapters that only contains figures

Tags: floats, positioning

I'm currently writing a rather long tex-Document and in general I'm pretty happy as of how figures are placed within my document.

But at the very end of the document I want a few pages (the last two chapters) that contain **only figures** and those figures should appear in the order I list them.

What would be the proper way to achieve this?

I know of the `totalnumber` and `textfraction` parameters, but as said, I don't want any changes within the rest of the document.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Would each of these figures be on a separate line?

Comment: Yes, in my case figures should appear on separate lines.
Don Hosek's answer does just that.

Comment: You should be able to use [hp!].  You only need the [h] option on the first and possibly last pages, and the [!] will ignore the topnumber etc limits.  You might want to add a \null after \chapter to handle \@afterheading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely what you want to do is load the `float` package and then use the `H` specifier on your floats which makes them not actually floats, but just places them in the output stream in order.

Preamble:

```
\usepackage{float}
```

Document:

```
\chapter{Figure only chapter}

\begin{figure}{H}
...
\caption{...}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}{H}
...
\caption{...}
\end{figure}

etc.
```